# Fill missing data in pandas based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have had this data frame before with missing data in `numbers` and `level3`, which are both different in dtypes (int + str). And i am looking to fill the data based on the `Org` column. The data in `numbers` and `level3` are always the same for each `Org` ID.

```
numbers = [np.nan, 5, 5, 5, np.nan,55,np.nan,55,55,np.nan,555,np.nan,555,555,np.nan]
Org = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1,2, 2, 2, 2, 2,3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
level3 = ["test", np.nan, "test", "test", np.nan, "failed", np.nan, "failed", "failed", "failed",np.nan,'try harder','try harder',np.nan,np.nan]
d = {'col1': numbers, 'col2': Org,'col3':level3}
inital = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

My desired output is the below:

```
numbers = [5, 5, 5, 5, 5,55,55,55,55,55,555,555,555,555,555]
Org = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1,2, 2, 2, 2, 2,3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
level3 = ["test", "test", "test", "test", "test", "failed", "failed", "failed", "failed", "failed",'try harder','try harder','try harder','try harder','try harder']
d = {'col1': numbers, 'col2': Org,'col3':level3}
final = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

I started by creating an extremely long loop to see if the org was the same, then applying the -1 or -2 or -3 or +1 or + 2 or +3 value if it wasn't empty. Still, it seemed ridiculously inefficient and didn't work perfectly, so I thought id come here to see if anyone had any tricks they could teach me.

Thank you

Comment: What about this, `inital.ffill().bfill()`?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try

```py
inital[['col1', 'col3']] = inital.groupby('col2').apply(lambda g: g[['col1', 'col3']].ffill().bfill())
```

```
print(inital)

     col1  col2        col3
0     5.0     1        test
1     5.0     1        test
2     5.0     1        test
3     5.0     1        test
4     5.0     1        test
5    55.0     2      failed
6    55.0     2      failed
7    55.0     2      failed
8    55.0     2      failed
9    55.0     2      failed
10  555.0     3  try harder
11  555.0     3  try harder
12  555.0     3  try harder
13  555.0     3  try harder
14  555.0     3  try harder
```

Comment: hmm i didn't try initall ffill or bfill before because i had Nan immediately before and after many variables, seen in my example; but i didnt realise it was automatically keep looking for a true value (i was worried i would be replacing Nan with Nan), so this is helpful. One question though, how do i make it obvious i only want to apply to col1 & col 3:

something like this:

inital.groupby('col2')['col1','col2'].apply(lambda g: g.ffill().bfill())

Comment: I needed to add axis=1 to ffill and bfill

Comment: @lapgoch `axis=1` is `fillna` along columns

Comment: hmm yeah, you're right. I am getting this error:

NotImplementedError: fillna with a method is not yet supported

i think its might be because my empties are 'none', actually?

Comment: @lapgoch Don't understand the error, will you get the error with your provided sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code - You can drop not required columns :

```
inital.assign(new_col3 = inital.groupby(['col2'])['col3'].transform('first'),
              new_col1 = inital.groupby(['col2'])['col1'].transform('max')
)
```

Output:

[image]